# Should I seperate two columns/entity classes/attributes into individual entities logical data model design

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I am designing a logical data model in Oracle data modeler. I have an entity called "Kitchen" (PK: Level) (E.g. Level 0/Ground floor as there is 1 kitchen per floor), according to the business rules each kitchen is assigned two chefs. I have an entity for chefs called 'Chefs' (PK: chef_id).

Do I:

- now have a multivalued entity class/column with two chef ids in my Kitchen entity?
- have a separate entity for chef_1 (PK: chef_1_no) and chef_2 (PK: chef_2_no) that are foreign keys in the Kitchen entity?
- or something else?

Comment: I would probably lean towards a single kiitchen having one column with multiple chefs.  Adding new columns for each new chef won't scale well.

Comment: So I would have two chef_ids within the chef_id FK of my Kitchen entity? Could you please explain what you mean by "won't scale well"? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know data modeler.  At the database level, my understanding is that you are asking whether chefs should be represented by a foreign key column in the kitchens table, _or_ should you add a new column for each of two chefs.

Comment: The latter option won't scale well because if at some later time you need say 10 chefs in a really large kitchen (e.g. in a hotel), you would have to add 10 columns to the kitchen table.

Comment: Correct I am asking whether I should or can insert two chef_ids as entity instances in the entity class of "chef_id" in my "Kitchen" entity

or

should I add two entity classes into my "Kitchen" entity, titled "chef1" and "chef2" and then these would become separate entities titled "chef1" and "chef2" which are both related then to the "Chef" entity.

Comment: As I said, I don't know your modelling tool.  Try both options and use the option will results in only one FK column.

Comment: I am just doing standard logical data model design

Comment: The purpose of data modelling is to understand _database_ design.  If you don't know the underlying reason for a design choice, there is no point in modelling.

Comment: I must add this kitchen will only ever have two chefs. Scalability shouldn't matter.

Comment: Then perhaps it is up to your preference.  If you can predict what sorts of queries you will be writing then maybe we can decide based on that.